# FileWriter not inserting run time integer values into a file?

Tags: java, filewriter

I tried to add the integer values in a `*.txt` file but instead it is printing ASCII values.

What is wrong with my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
      FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter("C:\\/New folder\\/file1.txt");
      Writer bw1=new BufferedWriter(f1);
      int j=0;
      while(j!=20)
      {
        j=j+1;
        bw1.write(j);
        bw1.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        bw1.flush();

        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
      f1.close();
}
```

Comment: Please remove any TAB characters from code you paste in here, they mess around with proper indentation. After pasting code in select the code block and press Ctrl+K to get the block displayed as code.

Comment: @Anthon i had inserted my code with proper indentation and also it was displaying as higlighted code. What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Your post was flagged by multiple people as needing improvement, before I got it, to help you out. One of the things was that your word `public` was indented more than the opening curly brace, The other that your opening and closing curly brace's indentation did not mask (see the edit history). That is correct Java, but IMO not properly indented, and unnecessarily difficult for humans to read (hence diminishing your chance of getting an answer). Currently the indentation depth is still inconsistent because of the tabs you were using.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i will improve on this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [the method in the `Writer` class that takes an `int` as an argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-), with the lower 16 bits of the `int` representing the Unicode code point, and the corresponding character being printed to the file as shown by this table:

[image: ascii table]

A simple fix would be to write strings to your file instead:

```
bw1.write(String.valueOf(j));
```

Comment: Thanks , but if you you could elaborately explain (int as argument part) that would be more better.

Comment: @salilvishnuKapur When you `write()` a single integer what you end up writing is the lower 8 bits of the `int` as a raw byte. That is not what you want if you intend to write the data as text. Also, the file path you use has issues: `\\/` is bogus.

Comment: @user268396 I got it                                                                                     But \\/ this is not bogus actually while setting path of the file i had to use escape character  \/  otherwise it was giving error .

Comment: Thanks TNT for helping .

Comment: @salilvishnuKapur the bogosity has nothing to do with whether or not the backslashes are properly escaped. In your string you wind up with a *double* directory separator in the path without a directory component (name) in between. **That** is bogus. Remove either the backslashes or the ordinary slashes to fix it.